# SPSS - how to rescale the x-axis

Tags: spss, x-axis

How to rescale the x-axis in spss? I have a graph like this:

[image]

I would like to rescale the x-axis from 1 to 5, even if the data for 1 and 5 has 0 percentages.

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should label all the values of the variable of the X axis for them to appear.
According to this source SPSS defaults at showing empty categories as long as they are labeled:
https://www.ibm.com/support/pages/how-display-empty-or-unselected-categories-spss-standard-charts

So, in syntax.
Value Label variable_of_x_axis
1 "1"
2 "2
3 "3"
4 "4"
5 "5".

Or you can label them using the user interface.